# How to create multiple Users and communicate between them in Erlang

Tags: oop, erlang

Let's look at the Java programming language (as an example), if I wanted to make a concept messaging app it would look similar to this:

```
class User {
    static List<User> users = new ArrayList();
    String name;

    User(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      users.add(this);
    }

    void sendMessage(String message) {
        for(User user : users) {
           user.messageReceived(message);
        }
    }

    void messageReceived(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

    String getName() { return name; } 
}
```

This code above is just to show how you can multiple Objects that can communicate with each other.

You can do the following to create users and send messages:

```
User bob = new User("Bob");
User john = new User("John");
User anne = new User("anne");
bob.sendMessage("Hello World!");
```

All the users that have been created will get bob's message.

I am trying to learn Erlang and am trying to recreate this similar sort of application. I want to be able to have different users communicate with each other.

I have tried many things like:

```
-module(test).
-export([sendMessage/1]).

sendMessage(M) -> 
    io:format(M, []).
```

What that does is just prints a message to the console. How can I have multiple users?

Is there a pattern or something to do this?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: For me you question look too blurred, maybe you should provide full Java code(for rewriting) or make it more specific. Now I can only recommend read about processes and message passing in any book about programming Erlang.

Comment: Hi, the Java code I provided I think is the best example I can provide. The User class a List of all User objects that have been created. There are 2 methods: sendMessage(message) which executes the messageReceived(message) that does the simple job of printing the message. You can see that all Users will see the message sent. If I added an extra method such as sendMessage(User, message) that could send a message to a specific user only. I am trying to recreate this concept in Erlang. I wrote the mock code without checking it works but (in theory) it should work fine! :)

Comment: Forgot to mention: I have checked message passing in Erlang on Google but cannot really see (or maybe I don't understand it) something that can relate to what I'm trying to achieve. I see things about creating a new process but that does not sound right.

Comment: In erlang Processes can communicate using messages. you can learn how to create process and pass message from one process to another. i will try to provide basic example.

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy to start with erlang until you have found the right entry point, so, although your question is in my opinion off topic, I will try to give you some info and comments.

**First** I recommend you to go to the site [LearnYouSomeErlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content), it is really a great resource to start with erlang and the functional programming, with a real stepwise approach. I think that the investment is more than valuable, at least it was the case for me.

**Next** I have commented your code, with some considerations about the changes that should be done for an erlang implementation.

```
class User {
```

There is no class concept in Erlang, and no object. The basic element is a process (a lightweight process, totally independent from the underlying operating system processes). Each process has a life-cycle, during its lifetime it is able to maintain a state.
This state may be any erlang term, and it will be lost as soon as the process will die.

```
static List<User> users = new ArrayList();
```

No static global variable. The only way to maintain a piece of information is, again, to store it in a process state,
either explicitly by passing the state as parameter of a server loop or implicitly by using some special storage such as ETS or mnesia database.
So to have something that hold the list of user names, you will need, for example, a server process registered as name_server holding the user name list in its state.
In most cases the application ensures that all the necessary servers are started before any client is started.

```
String name;
```

A process is able to maintain information. The basic structure of a process is

- a start function, in charge of spawning the process,
- an init function in charge of initializing the process state,
- and a loop which mainly contains a receive block that analyze the incoming messages, call some helper function depending on the message received and recursively loop by calling itself with an updated state.

  User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    users.add(this);
  }

The constructor is replaced by the 2 functions start and init. The start function as no real equivalent in the OOP, except that it relies on the system to allocate the necessary memory for internal data, message queue, stack... comparable to the automatic memory allocation for the object attributes in java or C++. Then it registers the process in the VM scheduler. The init is equivalent to the user defined constructor.

```
void sendMessage(String message) {
    for(User user : users) {
       user.messageReceived(message);
    }
}
```

Written this way, the sendMessage function does not depend on which object instance it belongs when executed since it uses only the static data of the class. So the closest translation could be an interface to the name sever. An interface is generally a piece of code belonging to a server module (same file!), exported for other modules, and which is executed in the client process context. The interface send a message to the server (its main role is to hide the communication protocol  with the server), and wait for a response (or not) if the access is synchronous (or not). In a real communication application, the request should come from a user, represented by a process in the system, and the flow would looks more like:

- the user send a request to its image process using an external interface (GUI program, shell, web interface...)
- the user process asks the name server all necessary information to reach the addressees
- the user process uses a user interface to send the message

it could be also possible to use the name server to send the message directly

```
void messageReceived(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

String getName() { return name; }
```

These 2 last functions are helper functions in the user process, they are triggered on message reception.

**Finally,** if you are interested, I have put an example of a chat system on [github minichat](https://github.com/pascalchap/minichat) which is rather simple and illustrates all the things discussed here (and some more) and includes documentation and comments.

Comment: Speechless, this is an amazing answer. I though of processes like threads or something heavy weight and your explanation of everything has made it much better to understand everything. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-module(chat).
-export([new/1, delete/1, send/3]).
-export([init_user/1]).

new(UserName)->
        spawn(?MODULE, init_user, [UserName]).
delete(Pid)->
        Pid ! stop.
send(From, To, Message)->
        To ! {message, From, Message}.
init_user(UserName)->
        io:format("Starting Client ~w with user name ~w~n",[self(), UserName]),
        wait_for_message(UserName).

wait_for_message(UserName)->
        receive
                {message, From, Message}->
                        io:format("Got Message From ~w And Message: ~s~n",[From, Message]),
                        wait_for_message(UserName);
                stop->
                        io:format("Stoping~w~n",[self()]);
                Message->
                        io:format("Unhandled Message:~w~n",[Message]),
                        wait_for_message(UserName)
        end.
```

To Simulate communication Between Processes example:-

```
c(chat).
Bob = chat:new("Bob").
John = chat:new("John").
Anne = chat:new("Anne").
chat:send(Bob, John, "Hello World!!").
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the example :)